# Meaning of the ?act=Submit

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
$("#fm-form").attr("action", "<?php print $this->Url; ?>index.php/general/geography/?act=Submit");
```

here `fm-form` is form id and this line of code is from .phtml file(Zend-Framework)

Can somebody explain me what is  "?act=submit"

Comment: It is a key-value pair that is accessible via the `$_GET` super global, i.e. `$_GET['act']`. `act` will be a key and `Submit` will be its value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is GET Method. `GET` is an associative array of variables passed to the current script via the URL parameters.

**Explanation**

The GET method sends the encoded user information appended to the page request. The page and the encoded information are separated by the ? character.

**For example**

We have this URL `http://www.test.com/index.htm?name1=value1&name2=value2`

**Features**

1. The GET method produces a long string that appears in your server
   logs, in the browser's Location: box.
2. The GET method is restricted to send upto 1024 characters only.
3. Never use GET method if you have password or other sensitive
   information to be sent to the server.
4. GET can't be used to send binary data, like images or word
   documents, to the server.
5. The data sent by GET method can be accessed using QUERY_STRING
   environment variable.
6. The PHP provides $_GET associative array to access all the sent
   information using GET method.

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

**Update 1**

In your situation, `?act=Submit` could be technique to check form is submitting or not.

Comment: i know this, index.php/general/geography/getgeography. In this getgeography is a Action in controller but i can't find ?act=submit

Comment: @AmolDavkhar you must read my answer again to understand.

Comment: found it, if (isset($_GET['act']) && $_GET["act"] == 'Submit')

Comment: @AmolDavkhar I have updated my answer again please see.